# where to validate the content of the JSON file?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a question, I have a seetings.json file and it has variables as shown
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASihX.png)

Trying to change the values of variables to null/empty during the build(added azure.yml below), I don't have any build errors but the file still has the committed changes
Azure.yml [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e9te.png)

Tried adding the File transform task after reading stack overflow, we don't have the deploy task configured in yml yet, In this case I am validating the changes in PR file commit(local feature branch) but still see the values for both variables.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbu8u.png)

Question: Is my approach to changing the content of the file is correct? if yes where do i find the modified contents of the file?

Comment: Please don’t post links to images of text.  Paste the actual text in the question *as text*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the changes have been published successfully. But since you use Microsoft-hosted agent, you may could not view the detailed output since the host image will be recycled by the server after the pipeline finished. So please kindly add a task to publish the output:

Then you should use something like this:

- task: FileTransform@1
  displayName: 'File transformation: seetings.json'
  inputs:
  folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/app//configs'
  targetFiles: '**/seetings.json'
  fileType: json
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
  PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/app//configs'
  ArtifactName: '**'

I hope it could do some help. Thanks.